# Is it good idea to declare config object in uvm_sequence_item

Tags: verilog, verification, system-verilog, uvm

I need to parametrize the `uvm_sequence_item` as my signal width change based on configuration.
Is it good idea to declare configuration object inside uvm_sequence_item?

Or is it possible to parametrize `uvm_sequence_item` like following?:

`class my_sequence#(int width) extends uvm_sequence_item;`

Answer (score 1):

The idea is that if you have a certain base class with a certain parameter, then subclasses that define different values for that parameter are not type compatible:

```
// base class
class my_base_class #(int PARAM = 1);
endclass
```

Subclasses with PARAM values 2 and 3 are not type compatible.

What you can do in your case is the following:

```
// common base class, no subclass
class my_base_item extends uvm_sequence_item;
  // ...
endclass

// parameterized class
class my_param_item #(int PARAM = 1) extends my_base_item;
  // ...
endclass
```

In your sequence you define your items as my_base_item:

```
class my_sequence extends uvm_sequence;
   my_base_item item;

   task body();
     item = my_base_item::type_id::create("item");
   endtask
endclass
```

And somewhere you set a type override depending on your config:

```
my_base_item::type_id::set_type_override(my_param_item #(32))::get_type(), 1);
```

I didn't test this out but it should work, because all parameterizations of 'my_param_item are still of type my_base_item.

In the driver you have to do some casting based on your param value:

```
task drive();
  // ...
  case (param) begin
    16:
      begin
        my_param_item #(16) m_item;
        $cast(m_item, item);  // item is the base item you got from the sequencer
        do_drive_16(m_item);
      end
    32:
      // ...
  end
endtask
```

You have to do casting like this, because you can't declare parameterizations based on dynamic values. The parameters have to be known at compile time.

Comment: So the base class would contain everything other than the parameterized fields, and the parameterized class would contain fields that are parameterized? How do you create a driver that uses this class? The driver code needs to know about all of the fields but if the driver is written to consume the base class then it won't have that information, right? I have tried something similar but got stuck at this point.

Comment: Does this mean that we also need to create a similar base class for the driver and do a factory override of the driver to match the sequence item?

Comment: Well, the driver does communicate with the sequencer using base items, but it also shares the same configuration as the sequence that started the parameterized items (or so it should). This means you can then cast. This only really works if you a limited number of parameter values, because you have to do some serious casting (see above).

Comment: If you have a lot of values for the parameter, I think @nguthrie 's idea of setting driver overrides will work better.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use the factory override mechanism instead of the config_db mechanism to choose chose the parameterized sequence/_item you want.

See below links. Its already mentioned there.

https://verificationacademy.com/cookbook/usingfactoryoverrides

https://forum.verificationacademy.com/forum/verification-methodology-discussion-forum/uvm-forum/31530-parameterized-uvm-sequence-item-and-usage-sequence

Comment: It's not clear from that article how to achieve the parameterization. It seems that changing the parameter will cause the override to fail. Maybe dave_59 will jump in with a code example?